# How exactly a crosscap relates to a Mobius strip, $^2$, and Klein bottle

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, non-orientable-surfaces, generalized-topology

Question 1: How exactly [a crosscap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cap) relates to a Mobius strip, a $^2$, and a Klein bottle?

I knew that

(1) Mobius strip glued the boundary with a disk $D^2$ is $^2$.

(2) Gluing the boundaries of two Mobius strip gives a Klein bottle

(3) Connecting sum two $^2$ gives $^2 \# ^2 $ =  Klein bottle.

Euler characteristic $\chi$:

- Mobius strip with $\chi=0$
- Disk with $\chi=1$
- $^2$ with $\chi=1$
- Klein bottle with $\chi=0$
- Question 2:  Crosscap has $\chi=?$

Comment: Crosscap is just another name for the Moebius band.

Comment: But Moebius band has 1 boundary, but the Crosscap has no boundary. Can we glue the boundary of a  Moebius band in some way to get a Crosscap? But a Moebius band glued the boundary with a disk 2 is 2...please illuminate?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by the crosscap. What is your definition?

Comment: definition from Wiki picture?

Comment: Sadly, what's written there is not a mathematical definition. They are attempting to describe a map from $RP^2$ to $R^3$. When one says "add a cross-cup to a surface with boundary", they mean "glue the Moebius band along a boundary curve."

Comment: My general suggestion is to read a topology textbook instead of relying on Wikipedia.

Comment: which topology books (as many as good as possible) you suggest?  Lol

Comment: My favorite for classification of surfaces in Massey's "Algebraic Topology."

Comment: Thanks, how about I use the definition in the [Fig 1 of this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.07285.pdf)?

Comment: They are so sloppy, it's hard to tell what they mean: When gluing surfaces from polygons one usually draws arrows to indicate the orientation, but they also use circles which a topologist would never use in this setting. For instance in part a of figure 1 it is either projective plane or the Klein bottle, depending on the orientation of the edges labeled by blue circles. In part d, you either get the torus or the Klein bottle. As I suggested, read Massey's book.